# html2canvas - the screenshotted canvas is always empty/blank

Tags: html2canvas

I have a div that i want to screenshot and save,

here is my code

```js
function _download(uri, filename)
{
    var el = $('.sf-download-button');
    if (el.length)
    {
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        if (typeof link.download === 'string')
        {
            link.href = uri;
            link.download = filename;
            document.body.appendChild(link);

            //simulate click // this causes page to download an empty html file not sure why
            link.click();

            //remove the link when done
            document.body.removeChild(link);
        }
        else
        {
            window.open(uri);
        }
    }
}
function _save()
{

    window.takeScreenShot = function ()
    {
        var a =document.getElementById("my-div");
        html2canvas(document.getElementById("the-div-that-i-want-to-screenshot"), {
            onrendered: function (canvas)
            {
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);
                a.append(canvas);

            },
            width: 220, 
            height: 310 
        });
    };


    $("#btnSave2").click(function ()
    {
        html2canvas(document.getElementById("data"), {
            onrendered: function (canvas)
            {
                _download_card(canvas.toDataURL(), 'save.png');
            }
        });
    });
}
```

This is the code i got it from web and added some of my own stuff.code was working i believe but right now, when I click on the button show me the image, it creates the image i can see it but it is just blank.

I tried every possible code combination from jsfiddle and all that and couldn't get anything different as a result.

What could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by simply changing the browser,

It was not working with Chrome but works perfectly on Mozilla.

Also i changed the code to this,

```
 $("#btnSave").click(function() {
    html2canvas($("#card"), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            theCanvas = canvas;
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);

            // Convert and download as image
            $("#img-out").append(canvas);
            // Clean up
            //document.body.removeChild(canvas);
        }
    });
});
```

Works perfect on Mozilla only.

Comment: This work for me:  


https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/882#issuecomment-698121822